# How to setState multiple states?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have Multiple properties and everyone has it own state. How do I state multiple states at the same time ? There is this one way

```
ChangeName(event){
        const details = this.state.details;
        details.first_name = event.target.value;
        this.setState({details: details});
    }
```

and bind it this way

```
this.ChangeName = this.ChangeName.bind(this);
```

So I have a form with these different properties

```
this.state={
        details :{first_name: "",
                last_name:"",
                address:"",
                company:"",
                number:"",
                dob:""
                }
```

So do I have create function for every property and bind everyone separately  the way I mentioned above ? Or is there any other way that I am not aware of as I am new to react.

Thank you !

Comment: `setState` checks for differences shallowly, so you'd have to clone your entire object and use that. Also, avoid mutating state, as this will prevent react from handling things properly.

Comment: I don't get it so I have to do it separate for everyone ?

Comment: Yes you will need an event handler for every input you have.

What @DoMiNeLa10 means with avoid mutating state is that you are reading the `details` object from the state and then mutate it's `first_name` property. In react you should never mutate state. I'd recommend to lift your properties to the top level state and then simply `this.setState({ first_name: event.target.value })`

Comment: Okay thank you very much ! :)

Comment: @sventschui that is very misleading that you need a separate event handler for each input

Comment: @charlietfl can you elaborate a bit?

Comment: @sventschui point is you can have one handler for many inputs

Comment: You don't need a separate event handler for every property in state, you can just use a closure.

Comment: can you elaborate a bit about closure ?

Answer (score 9):

To answer your question about updating multiple properties of the state: You can absolutely do this. `setState` accepts an object with updates. Thus `setState({ foo: '', bar: '' })` will update the `foo` and `bar` properties.

---

To answer what I think you meant:

When working with input fields the way to go is to create an event handler function for each field.

See the two examples of how to properly handle input fields with nested state or with top level state. I'd recommend to keep the fields top-level in the state as otherwise you'll have to deal with

- [the asynchroneous nature of setState](https://vasanthk.gitbooks.io/react-bits/patterns/19.async-nature-of-setState.html)
- [deep object cloning in order to not mutate objects within the state](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/handling-state-in-react-four-immutable-approaches-to-consider-d1f5c00249d5)

https://codepen.io/sventschui/pen/yxPrjP

```
class AppWithDetails extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.onFirstNameChange = this.onFirstNameChange.bind(this);
    this.onLastNameChange = this.onLastNameChange.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      details: { first_name: '', last_name: '' }
    }
  }

  onFirstNameChange(event) {
    // store value because of react synthetic events
    const value = event.target.value;

    // use callback function in setState because of asynchronous nature of setState
    this.setState(function(state) {
      return { 
        details: Object.assign({}, 
          state.details, {
          first_name: value 
        })
      }
    })
  }

  onLastNameChange(event) {
    // store value because of react synthetic events
    const value = event.target.value;

    // use callback function in setState because of asynchronous nature of setState
    this.setState(function(state) {
      return { 
        details: Object.assign({}, 
          state.details, {
          last_name: value 
        })
      }
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        State:
        <pre>{JSON.stringify(this.state)}</pre>
        <input type="text" onChange={this.onFirstNameChange} value={this.state.details.first_name} />
        <input type="text" onChange={this.onLastNameChange} value={this.state.details.last_name} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class AppWithoutDetails extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.onFirstNameChange = this.onFirstNameChange.bind(this);
    this.onLastNameChange = this.onLastNameChange.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      first_name: '',
      last_name: '',
    }
  }

  onFirstNameChange(event) {
    this.setState({ first_name: event.target.value })
  }

  onLastNameChange(event) {
    this.setState({ last_name: event.target.value })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        State:
        <pre>{JSON.stringify(this.state)}</pre>
        <input type="text" onChange={this.onFirstNameChange} value={this.state.first_name} />
        <input type="text" onChange={this.onLastNameChange} value={this.state.last_name} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) { 
  ReactDOM.render(<AppWithoutDetails />, document.getElementById('withoutdetails'));
  ReactDOM.render(<AppWithDetails />, document.getElementById('withdetails'));
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use a curried function and use bracket notation to set different props of the details:

```
changeDetail(name) {
    return event => {
      this.setState(({ details }) => ({
        details: { ...details, [name]: event.target.value }
      }));
    };
  }
```

Then you can use it like this in the `render()` ed elements:

```
  <input
      onChange={this.changeDetail("lastName")}
      value={this.state.details.lastName}
    />

    <input
      onChange={this.changeDetail("address")}
      value={this.state.details.address}
    />
```

Comment: But you have pass name only in it ?

Comment: how do I add address in it ?

Answer (score -2):

```js
ChangeName(event){
        this.setState({
           details:{ first_name: 'jack', last_name:'high'}
      });
}
render(){
  const {details} = this.state
  console.log(details.first_name)
}
```